# Парсинг подробных характеристик Хотлайн Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautiful-soup

Не выходит спарсить подробные характеристики со страницы продукта на хотлайне. Дело в том что там нужно нажать на кнопку, и они появляются, но selenium почему то не видит появившиеся характеристики . Дайте пожалуйста совет как спарсить подробные характеристики например с этой страницы https://hotline.ua/dom-matrasy/veres-baby-95x45/

Comment: Используйте неявные ожидания

Comment: Вам стоит добавить в вопрос чать проблемного кода.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вся подробная информация есть сразу, потому что никаких Аяксов там нет, это сделано CSS псевдо-элементом `after`.

Вы можете загрузить всю информацию обратившись к нужным элементам по Xpath.
К примеру `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-specification-box]/text()')` сразу после загрузки страницы командой `browser.get()` загрузит текстовое описание))

Answer (score -1):

Скорее всего контент подгружается Ajax. Поэтому используйте неявные ожидания.

Например:

```
dialog_window = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.dialog-content-277.dialog-content-transition-self-320.dialog-content-transition-entered-322")))
```

Данный код ожидает появление в течении 15 секунд div

Comment: Не нужно ему явное ожидание, потому что Аякса там нет. Переход между "основные" и "подробные" сделан CSS-ом. То есть вся инфа есть сразу